# How to cancel and keep reverse-i-search?

Tags: bash, command-history, line-editor

Often I fail to find something with reverse-i-search but want to keep what I have already written. For example, typing `pdflatex` fails to complete to `pdflatex mydocument.tex`. If I then cancel it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd>, the `pdflatex` part is deleted as well. How can I cancel it in a way that keeps my input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of cancelling just use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>  (or on Ubuntu alternatively <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd> to move the cursor to the end of the first word and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to delete everything to the end of the line.

Now you are ready to complete your command.

Comment: Thanks! <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd> works on Arch Linux under Z shell as well.

Comment: Neither Alt+F nor Ctrl+→ work in my `mintty`/`Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`/`bash 4.3.11(1)-release` environment.